# Href doesn’t work in ion-option-button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

hy guys,
in an Ionic project I made a ion-list ion-items and these ion-option-buttons:

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="(id,place) in places" >

    <h2>{{place.name}}</h2>

    <ion-option-button class="button-positive" href="#/tab/place/{{id}}">
      edit
    </ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>
```

but href="..." is not working

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem:

template:

```
<ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="goTo('edit-place',{'placeId':id})">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.goTo=function (state,params) {
    $state.go(state,params);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In angularJS, The correct way to use href is

```
<a ng-href="#/tab/place/{{id}}"></a>
```

[ng-href Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using This

> 

```
<h2>{{place.name}}</h2>

<ion-option-button class="button-positive">
 <a href="#/tab/place/{{id}}">
  edit
 </a> 
</ion-option-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Href attribute is supposed to be use with anchor tag. You can try to wrap ion-option-button with anchor tag or use event like onClick to navigate using javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ui-router you don't need to make a goTo function.  Just use ui-sref to load your dynamic state. Also I would try not to use "-" in the state name (editPlace).

```
<ion-option-button class="button-positive" ui-sref="edit-place({placeId:id})">edit</ion-option-button>
```